# Merge all files in a directory into one using bash

Tags: bash

I have a directory with several *.js files. Quantity and file names are unknown. Something like this:

```
js/
 |- 1.js
 |- 2.js
 |- blabla.js
```

I need to merge all the files in this directory into one `merged_dmYHis.js`. For example, if files contents are:

**1.js**

```
aaa
bbb
```

**2.js**

```
ccc
ddd
eee
```

**blabla.js**

```
fff
```

The `merged_280120111257.js` would contain:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
eee
fff
```

Is there a way to do it using bash, or such task requires higher level programming language, like python or similar?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

```
cat 1.js 2.js blabla.js > merged_280120111257.js
```

general solution would be:

```
cat *.js > merged_`date +%d%m%Y%H%M`.js
```

Just out of interest - do you think it is a good idea to name the files with DDMMYYYYHHMM? It may be difficult to sort the files chronologically (within the shell). How about the YYYYMMDDHHMM pattern?

```
cat *.js > merged_`date +%Y%m%d%H%M`.js
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not think the answer is so simple. In what order `cat` merge files?

Comment: @SilverLight - in the same order you give them. As `*.js` (in `ls *.js`) returns them in alphabetical order, so will they be concatenated with `cat *.js`.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the incoming files as well, the default is alphabetical order, but this example goes through from oldest to the newest by the file modification timestamp:

```
cat `ls -tr *.js` > merged_`date +%Y%m%d%H%M`.js
```

In this example cat takes the list of files from the ls command, and -t sorts by timestamp, and -r reverses the default order.