# R tabulate large table

Tags: r, large-data

I have an huge table (millions of rows and 2 columns) similar to the one below.

1. FIELD1   FIELD2
2. M01      ABC
3. M02      ABC
4. MO3      ABC
5. M03      CDE
6. M04      FGH
7. M05      LMN
8. M06      FGH
9. ...      ...

FIELD1 may have millions of unique values and FIELD2 may have up to 10,000 unique value.
I am using the following statement in R to read the txt file and to tabulate it:

```
dat<-read.table(file.choose(new = FALSE), sep = "\t")
m=table(dat)
```

However it returns the following error

*Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1.5 Gb
R(390,0xac0442c0) malloc:*  mmap(size=1599119360) failed (error code=12)
 *error: can't allocate region*
 set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
R(390,0xac0442c0) malloc:  *mmap(size=1599119360) failed (error code=12)*
 error: can't allocate region
* set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug*

Any idea how to overcome this limit?
Many thanks.

Comment: Did you get the error with the `read.table` part, or the `table` part? That is, did you succeed in reading your dataset into R before trying to tabulate it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extend memory size limit in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749058/extend-memory-size-limit-in-r)

Comment: Also take a look at the bigmemory package.

Comment: What OS are you using?  Is it 64-bit?  How much memory do you have?  Did you recently restart your system?  Windows is notorious for fragmenting memory....

Comment: Welcome to big data. http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html

Comment: Slightly OT, but FIELD1 may have a data cleanliness issue if your example is accurate. In row4, there is `MO3` rather than `M03`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`table` will try to create a matrix of `length(unique(FIELD1))` by `length(unique(FIELD2))`, presumably many times the size of your original data; a more efficient representation is as a data frame of counts, along the lines of

```
lst <- with(test, lapply(split(as.character(FIELD1), FIELD2), table))
df <- data.frame(FIELD1 = unlist(lapply(lst, names), use.names=FALSE), 
                FIELD2 = rep(names(lst), sapply(lst, length)),
                Count = unlist(lst, use.names=FALSE))
```

This could be represented as a sparse matrix

```
library(Matrix)
m <- with(df, {
    sparseMatrix(as.integer(FIELD1), as.integer(FIELD2), x=Count, 
                 dimnames=list(levels(FIELD1), levels(FIELD2)))
})
```

leading to

```
> m
7 x 4 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
    ABC CDE FGH LMN
M01   1   .   .   .
M02   1   .   .   .
M03   .   1   .   .
M04   .   .   1   .
M05   .   .   .   1
M06   .   .   1   .
MO3   1   .   .   .

> colSums(m)
[1] 3 1 2 1
```

Comment: Actually what I would need is a matrix (Field1,Field2) on which I have to make some matricial operations. The only solution I see now is to go vector by vector.

Comment: The Matrix package has a sparse matrix representation that might be sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

This solution uses a single `read.csv.sql` statement to read the data into an SQLite database (which it automatically creates), perform the calculation in the database (not in R) and then only read it into R after the calculation has ben performed.  Thus although it does not do a `table` it still shows which FIELD1 values are associated with each FIELD2 value and does so via a more compact representation.

First create some test data:

```
# create test file
test <- data.frame(FIELD1 = c("M01", "M02", "MO3", "M03", "M04", "M05", "M06"), 
    FIELD2 = c("ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "CDE", "FGH", "LMN", "FGH"))
write.csv(test, file = "test.csv", row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
```

Then try this:

```
library(sqldf)
DF <- read.csv.sql("test.csv", 
    sql = "select FIELD2, group_concat(FIELD1) FIELD1 from file group by FIELD2")
```

With the test data the result is:

```
>  DF
  FIELD2      FIELD1
1    ABC M01,M02,MO3
2    CDE         M03
3    FGH     M04,M06
4    LMN         M05
```