# R import large files

Tags: r

My computer can't handle the importation of a particularly large text file (I get error - cannot allocate vector of size...).

I'm using the following code :

```
data<-read.table("file.txt",header = TRUE,sep = ";",
                      dec = ",", quote = "", strip.white = TRUE,)
```

As I only need to use the data corresponding to females within the file, is there any way to directly import just the females (data$sex==2).

...I'm using windows 8, the file has 88 variables (integers, factors and characters) of which I'm interested in abut 5 of them.

Comment: What OS are you using? What is the structure of your files. Show a few lines (you can read in a few with `nrows = 5` argument to `read.table`).

Comment: If the data will fit in your ram, you might be able to read it by supplying the `n` and `colClasses` arguments.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14294217/reading-large-files-into-r/14294242#14294242

Comment: Maybe use `scan` in a loop with the `skip` argument, and delete the unwanted portions before reading in the next chunk.

Comment: Thanks, the skip method allows me to import my data, even if it is a convoluted process.